# Why Gant does not fail on positive integer returning target?

Tags: groovy, gant

When I have the following `build.gant`

```
target(example: 'example target') {
  echo(message: "name : ${it.name}, description: ${it.description}")
}

target(alwaysFails: 'never succeed') {
  27
}
```

If I run `gant alwaysFails`, the build failed.
But if I run `gant alwaysFails example`, the build succeeded.

Actually I expected build failed and 'example' target did not run.

How can I make gant stop on target failure?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to make the targets depend on each other, so

```
target(alwaysFails: 'never succeed') {
  27
}

target(example: 'example target') {
  depends( alwaysFails )
  echo( message: "name : ${it.name}, description: ${it.description}" )
}
```

Then running:

```
gant example
```

Will run `alwaysFails` and then run `example` if it succeeds (which it never does).  This way I believe you get the functionality you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that `alwaysFailes` is an optional target. I must not make `example` depend on `alwaysFails`.
It's something like `clean` and `compile` targets. Sometimes we need to call `gant clean compile` but, `compile` should not depend on `clean`

Answer (score 0):

I make the target throws an exception when it has to fail always. It works.

```
throw new RuntimeException('error message..')
```